# What does "$\cdots$" mean in $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-r+2)}{(r-1)!}a^{n-r+1}b^{r-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

In the formula,

$$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-r+2)}{(r-1)!}a^{n-r+1}b^{r-1}$$

what does the "$\cdots$" mean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means: "There are too many terms to write, but follow the obvious pattern to fill them in".

In your example, you subtract $1$ from a factor to get the next factor. I might read that aloud as "$n$ times $n-1$ times $n-2$ all the way down to $n-r+2$".

As another example, 
$$
3 + 6 + 9 + \cdots + 3n
$$
would indicate the sum of all positive multiples of $3$ less than or equal to $3n$.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Simple. Easy to understand. Does this mean that I should solve the $(n-r+2)$ first?

Comment: @DantheMan Probably the $r$ in this case is meant to be some fixed constant. For example, if $r = 5$, then your formula simplifies to $$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!}a^{n-4}b^4.$$ I can't really say more without context.

Comment: Actually, this is the formula for finding the $r$th term of a binomial $(a+b)^r$

Comment: Ah right.. the $r$th term of $(a+b)^n$. What I mean by that is, should I solve $(n-r+2)$ first, so that I know when the obvious pattern of $\cdots$ ends?

Comment: @DantheMan There are (at least) two ways to think about it. One is what you are suggesting: "Since $r = 5$, the last number in my pattern is a 3." Another way is to notice that there are always $r-1$ factors in the product. So you might think: "Since $r = 5$, I keep following the pattern until I've written four factors down."

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @Dan Not only may there be too many terms, but, the number of terms may not be fixed, e.g. $\,r-1\,$ terms in your product

Answer (score 3):

Writing it as "$\cdots\;$", would be better than "$\dots\;$" . It indicates a product:

$$
\frac{n(n-1)(n-2) \cdots (n-r+2)}{(r-1)!}a^{n-r+1}b^{r-1}
=\frac{\prod_{k=0}^{r-2} (n-k)}{(r-1)!}a^{n-r+1}b^{r-1}
$$

Comment: This would be better as a comment.

Comment: @Chaz, doesn't it answer the question?

Comment: For those of us who *already know the answer*, it may be sufficient. But for someone who doesn't know...? Either way, no big deal

Comment: Also, I'm fairly certain that there was a ninja edit to this answer

Comment: ...as there was to the question.

Comment: At first it only said, Writing it as "$\cdots\;$", would be better than "$\dots\;$".

Comment: That's probably why @TheChaz said that.

Comment: I thought about giving it more detail, BEFORE I read the comments. Is that wrong? "Either way, no big deal "

Comment: Ah yeah. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

It means multiplying a set of terms ($n$, $n-1$, $n-2$, $\dots$(!), $n-(r-2)$) when each term is the result of subtracting $0$, $1$, $2$, $\dots$, $r-2$ from $n$, respectively.